# Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema'

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I am going through the official tutorial provided by [graphene-python](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/) for their library.

I, like a few others I have seen online, am having some serious issues trying to simply import the schema file within the project folder (project_name/schema.py). For reference, the project_name is cookbook as it is denoted within the tutorial.

This is within my settings.py:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'cookbook.schema.schema'
}
```

and this is in the schema file tiself (project_name/schema.py):

```
import graphene

import cookbook.schema


class Query(cookbook.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    # This class will inherit from multiple Queries
    # as we begin to add more apps to our project
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: module 'cookbook' has no attribute 'schema'.
```

I have also tried a few other tutorials as well, but haven't had any luck. My project is on django 2.0.2 and graphene 2.0.1. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had incompatible versions of Django, Graphene and Django-environ.

To solve, I made a virtualenv using mkvirtualenv. After that, I was able to follow [this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/1-getting-started/) without any issues. It is capable of being stood up without a virtual environment, but it was far easier to just define one and get moving with a clean slate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your installed apps?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'graphene_django',
]
```

the error says that cookbook has no attribute schema.
Therefore the import `cookbook.schema` is not working in your schema.py
the example says

```
import cookbook.ingredients.schema
```

Comment: After adding the more direct import (import cookbook.ingredients.schema),  I get this error:

Could not import 'cookbook.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookbook.ingredients'.

Comment: @ChadVanDeHey Did you add cookbook to your installed apps?

Comment: Yes, assume that I've completed the tutorial as directed.